# Multiple variable assignments and IBOutlets in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, interface-builder

I come from an Objective-C background and I'm currently in the process of getting into Swift a bit more. All seems to be going well at the moment but I've hit a slight annoyance. In Objective-C, I used to be able to assign multiple IBOutlets on one line like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *emailField, *passwordField;
```

So I'd like to do the same in Swift, rather than having a line for every single view. I've tried:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailField, passwordField : UITextField?
```

Which seems like legal Swift code, the app compiles, but in Interface Builder I can only see the emailField outlet.

My question is, can this be done in Swift? If so how?

Comment: While I don't know that it can't be done, it is much clearer code to write each declaration on it's own line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple IBOutlets in same line of same type in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213467/multiple-iboutlets-in-same-line-of-same-type-in-swift)