# Multiple IBOutlets in same line of same type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

In objective c you can declare IBOutlets in below mentioned manner:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1, *btn2, *btn3;
```

And you can able to bind these buttons in storyboard.

Now I want to use the same terminology in Swift. I want to declare these 3 buttons in same line rather than declaring these in 3 different lines. I can be able to declare these buttons in Swift as well using:

```
@IBOutlet var btn1, btn2, btn3: UIButton!
```

But my problem is I can only able to bind "btn1" in storyboard. "btn2" & "btn3" are not showing up in the Connection Inspector.

I don't want to use UIOutletCollection class.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614623/multiple-variable-assignments-and-iboutlets-in-swift ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also but it didn't worked. The thing is in connection inspector it displays btn1 only.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options to get them in a single line.

The first is to use a **Referencing Outlet Collection** by defining this:

```
@IBOutlet var fields: Array<UITextField> = []
```

Then link your text fields to that. You can then access them as `fields[0]` and `fields[1]` respectively.

[image]

The other option is to define them in your file like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
```

Make your connections from Interface Builder, then edit the declarations to be in a single line like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!, passwordField: UITextField!
```

About you only options I'm afraid.