# attach multiple UITextFields to one iBOutlet

Tags: uitextfield, swift4, ios-simulator

I want to link multiple UITextFields to one iBOutlet.  I have tried the suggestion from the following link [Multiple IBOutlets in same line of same type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213467/multiple-iboutlets-in-same-line-of-same-type-in-swift)

But this did not work as I got the following error.

```
'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 
'Array<UITextField>'

 @IBOutlet weak var driverTextField: Array<UITextField>=[]
```

[image: Simulator and code side by side.]

Basically, I want to connect the last 3 UITextfields in the simulator to the driverTextfield.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var driverTextField: Array<UITextField>=[]
```

The compiler rightly complains that you can't say `weak` with an array. But you need an array in order to make an outlet collection. So just delete `weak` and you'll be fine.

> Basically, I want to connect the last 3 UITextfields in the simulator to the driverTextfield

Yup, once you delete `weak`, your code will compile and you'll be able to configure that in Interface Builder (storyboard).

Comment: will removing "weak" doesn't effect or get memory leaks?

Comment: @Sanju Not really. No law requires `IBOutlet` references to be `weak`. It is customary but not absolutely necessary. Just make sure your subviews don't have a strong reference to the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

you could make an "outlet collection" instead. and access each of the outlets with and for loop and index.
`@IBOutlet var driverTextField: [UITextField]!`

[image: Select outlet collection from dropdown]

Select the outlet collection from the dropdown and drag and drop all outlets of textfields to this outlet.